# Run scripts in php

Tags: php, python, web

I am running a python script through my php. It works fine on console but returns null when I run it on browser.I even tried writing output to a file, but it doesn't return anything. 
The php code is:

```
<?php

$y = "python Code.py";

$output = shell_exec($y);

if($output!=null){
echo $output;
}
else {
echo "No output";
}




$myfile = fopen("test.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

fwrite($myfile, $output);

fclose($myfile);


?>
```

Comment: Does it work if you specify the full path to your Python script in `$y`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/custom/test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;

#!/usr/bin/env python **is this in the first line of you python script?** 
chmod +x /usr/custom/test.py
```

Comment: It is the first line. It does execute the script if I run it directly as "php test.php" on my terminal.

Comment: Have you try escapeshellcmd?